# Aggregation query with $set in findOneAndUpdate doesn't update document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using node 11.6, mongodb 4.2.5, mongoose 4.3.17. I am trying to update a field by adding a string to the end of it. I first updated to mongo 4.2 which I apparently needed to use aggregation pipelines in updates.

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868963/append-a-string-to-the-end-of-an-existing-field-in-mongodb) like this:

```
var update = [{$set: {slug: {$concat: ['$slug', '-rejected']}}}];
Content.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, update, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
//
});
```

but when I ran it I got no error, no document returned, and it was not updated.

So I removed the outer [], and passed just an object like this:

```
var update = {$set: {slug: {$concat: ['$slug', '-rejected']}}}
Content.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, update, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
//
});
```

And I receive this error message:

```
`Cast to string failed for value "{ '$concat': [ '$slug', '-rejected' ] }" at path "slug"`,
```

What does this mean? How can I accomplish this? (without two separate calls)

Running the same function but replacing update with:

```
var update = {slug: 'test-slug'}
```

successfully updates the slug to 'test-slug'.

But trying to do the same simple thing with an aggregation acts much like my previous attempt, no error or change:

```
var update = [{$set: {slug: 'test-sluggy'}}]
```

Using `updateOne()` instead of `findOneAndUpdate()` doesn't change anything either.

The only thing I can think that could cause it is the mongoose version, but it seems like there's a lot of changes between 4 and 5 and I don't want to update unless I have to, but I can't find anything that says it would change anything.

Comment: Mongoose `4.3.17` is so old, I've recently updated to latest `5.9` just for DB upgrade to `4.2.x` as mongoose `5.7` or above & internal mongodb `3.3` or above is recommended for MongoDB `4.2`, Give it a try !!

Comment: @whoami thanks, it seems that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline form requires that the update be an array of pipeline stages.

Try wrapping your existing update in `[]` like

```
var update = [{$set: {slug: {$concat: ['$slug', '-rejected']}}}]
```

Comment: when i do this, it returns with no error, and the document is unchanged

Comment: Try doing a `find` with the same filter to make sure it matches like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

we can use something like that

```
var update = [{ $set: { slug: { $concat: ['$slug', '-rejected'] } } }]
```

starting from mongo versions > 4.2, the update operations can accept an aggregation pipeline, so we are able to update some field based on its current value:

the whole query may be something like that

```
Content.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id }, // the find criteria
    [{ $set: { slug: { $concat: ['$slug', '-rejected'] } } }], // this is the update aggregation pipeline, see the square brackets
    { multi: true }, // this should be set to true if you have more than one document to update, 
    // otherwise, only the first matching document will be updated, 
    // this is in case you use update rather than findOneAndUpdate, 
    // but here we have only one document to update, so we can ignore it
    (err, doc) => {
    //
});
```

Comment: like what i tried with my code, running this exact code returns no error, but leaves the document unchanged.

Comment: did you try adding {returnNewDocument: true} to get the new document after the update?

Comment: regardless of being returned, checking the document separately after proves that it remains unchanged

Comment: Ah yes, I thought it was updated but you can’t retrieve that update from the query ... I’ve tried it many times on mongo shell and it’s working fine, my mongo version is 4.2.5 ...could you double check your mongo version?

Comment: also make sure that the id you passed to the filter object exists and exactly match the _id of the document you want to update

Comment: > db.version(): 4.2.5. I know the id is right because changing to a non aggregate update object works fine. Only thing I can think of is the mongoose version.