# MongoDB: How to append to a string in a deep nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a hobbyist web programmer who just started learning MongoDB/Mongoose and I can't seem to figure out how to append to a string located in a deep nested array. I am trying to append a string to the end of `hours: String`. Below is the Schema I'm working with:

```
const TestSchema = new Schema({
    userID: Number, 
    years: [
        {
            year: Number,
            months: [{
                month: Number,
                days: [{
                    day: Number,
                    hours: String
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is what I have so far. I tried to extend upon this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589089 .But this is giving me a `Cannot specify arrayFilters and a pipeline update` error.

```
TestModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "years.months.days.day": 12 },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        "years.$[index1].months.$[index2].days.$[index3].hours": {
          $concat: [
            "$years.$[index1].months.$[index2].days.$[index3].hours",
            " 44:44:44"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "index1.year": 2020 },
      { "index2.month": 7 },
      { "index3.day": 12 }
    ]
  }
).catch(error => {
  console.log("error>>" + error);
});
```

Edit: Below is code with which I created an instance of the model

```
var test = new TestModel({
    userID: 5,
    years: [{
        year: 2020, 
        months: [{
            month: 7,
            days: [{
                day: 12,
                hours: "4:4:4 5:5:5"
            }]
        }]
    }]
})

test.save().then(function(){
    console .log("testSaved>>" + !test.isNew);
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the data in the db:
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to remove the brackets around `$set`? actually you can leave the condition blank `{ "years.months.days.day": 12 }` to this `{}`

Comment: @Ifaruki I removed the square brackets which then gives me `error>>CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ '$concat': [ '$years.$[index1].months.$[index2].days.$[index3].hours', ' 44:44:44' ] }" at path "hours"`

Comment: Why do you need aggregate update i.e because of `$concat`?

Comment: @Ifaruki `hours` is a `String` as you can see in the schema i posted. The value of hours in the single instance in db is `"4:4:4 5:5:5"`

@Gibbs I was pretty much following the code in the post I referred to

Comment: @turivishal Yup, done

Comment: @Aj_ Just confirming you want to update this `4:4:4 5:5:5` to this `4:4:4 5:5:5 44:44:44` right?

Comment: @turivishal Yeah, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update is not supporting both operation together "arrayFilters" and "aggregation pipeline", you need to use only single operation from both,

So here you need to use only [update aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html), using nested `$map`,

```
TestModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    years: {
      $elemMatch: {
        year: 2020,
        months: {
          $elemMatch: {
            month: 7,
            days: { $elemMatch: { day: 12 } }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  [{
    $set: {
      years: {
        $map: {
          input: "$years",
          as: "y",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$y",
              {
                months: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$y.months",
                    as: "m",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$m",
                        {
                          days: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$m.days",
                              as: "d",
                              in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                  "$$d",
                                  {
                                    hours: {
                                      $cond: {
                                        if: { 
                                          $and: [
                                            { $eq: ["$$y.year", 2020] },
                                            { $eq: ["$$m.month", 7] },
                                            { $eq: ["$$d.day", 12] }
                                          ] 
                                        },
                                        then: { $concat: ["$$d.hours", " 44:44:44"] },
                                        else: "$$d.hours"
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Just curious, looking at the size of the code required, is it a bad practice to use nested arrays in mongodb?

Comment: depends on the project features, how data required and how your are storing in db, sometime its good, and sometime its bad, i am not sure why you are storing just dates in nested array, but there should be simple ways to store instead of nested array. and if you say code size, i think this is the only direct way to update using single query, otherwise you can do using 2 queries.