# How to concat new string value with existing value in mongoengine while doing update?

Tags: mongoengine, django-mongodb-engine

I want concat new string value with existing value.

suppose i have 3 document in my collection

```
{
   "field" : "some"
}
{
   "field" : "value"
}
{
   "field" : "test"
}
```

i want to write a update query which will concat "new" with existing value . My updated documents will look like

```
{
   "field" : "some new"
}
{
   "field" : "value new"
}
{
   "field" : "test new"
}
```

Comment: looks like it's already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868963/append-a-string-to-the-end-of-an-existing-field-in-mongodb

Comment: i want a mongoengine update query